# Why when I install a environment with conda it does not give me the latest version

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

So I have an old version of conda install

```
conda -V
conda 4.5.4
```

the current version of anaconda is 5.1 and it is running python 3.6.4

I wanted to test my code base on the newer version of conda so I tought I could install a new env first with conda and it would give me the latest version of the conda distribution

```
conda create -n py364 python=3.6 anaconda
```

I thought this would be installing the latest anaconda with python 3.6.4 but it is actually installing python 3.6.1

is it possible to install the new anaconda version in a env?

Comment: `conda create` followed by `conda update python`?

Comment: @darthbith yes that was my problem! thanks, you can post answer so I accept it!

Answer (score 0):

It can depends on your environement.

Test: `conda search python` to see the available versions for your environement.

Have you tried: `conda create -n py364 python=3.6.4 anaconda` ?

Answer (score 0):

as @darthbith suggested in the comments

you should always update your conda version using

```
conda update conda
```

then if you call

```
conda create -n py364 python=3.6 anaconda
```

it will install the latest distribution of anaconda on the with python 3.6.

or you could also call

```
conda create -n conda51 anaconda=5.1
```

to install the actual distribution you are targeting